# Referencing variables that are not strings

Tags: powershell

I want to reference properties selected from a cmdlet and then use them later on in my script as `$mailboxarray.totalitemsize` and `$mailboxarray.totalitemsize`

This is breaking later on in my script as I assume it doesn't like the type of object it is. How can I make anything I pull into the references a string? At the moment I am getting "No mapping exists from object type `System.Management.Automation.PsObject` to a known managed provider type". My code at the moment: the first command works fine but I can't use expandproperty when there are multiple entries like line two?

```
$recipienttype = Get-mailbox -identity $recordset.PrimarySmtpAddress | Select -expandproperty RecipientTypeDetails

$mailboxarray = Get-Mailbox -identity $recordset.PrimarySmtpAddress | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select-object totalitemsize, lastlogontime
```

Comment: Please add the exact, complete error message as well as a code sample that allows to reproduce the problem to your question.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to pass these values as string arguments to a database provider. You can convert to a string using the **[string]** cast operator or the **ToString** method, but conversion to a string when a string argument is expected is normally done automatically if possible, so explicit conversion shouldn't be necessary. Based on the error message and description, it sounds like the problem is more likely to be that you're trying to pass **$mailboxarray** to some method as an argument array, but actually the value will always be a PSCustomObject, never an array.

Comment: Anyway, without the complete error message and the code that produces it, you're leaving too much to inference. I *think* I can guess what the problem is, but I'll wait for you to provide sufficient information to take the guesswork out of it. Please read [Jon Skeet's blog post](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR) for advice on how to ask good questions.